# Sort list of sublists in lisp

Tags: list, sorting, lisp, common-lisp, sublist

I'm trying to sort the elements of the following list by using the third element of each sublist:

```
    ((v 1 a) (v 3 d) (v 6 b) (v 2 c))
```

So the result should be:

```
    ((v 1 a) (v 6 b) (v 2 c) (v 3 d))
```

I've tried something like this:

```
    (sort (copy-seq my-list) #'> :key (lambda (x) (third (car x))) )
```

but it doesn't really work and I'm not sure how should I do this.

Answer (score 4):

```
CL-USER 15 > (sort (copy-seq '((v 1 a) (v 3 d) (v 6 b) (v 2 c)))
                   #'string<
                   :key #'third)
((V 1 A) (V 6 B) (V 2 C) (V 3 D))
```